# ubuntu 14.04 no sound no settings

Tags: gnome, sound

I upgraded to 14.04 after a few days my sound was gone and now the menu on system settings is incomplete items have disappeared I've been in forums looking and searching for answers I cannot connect to the internet using a dongle and no WiFi can be detected Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-29-generic i686) please help

I been running various sudo apt-get install commands non have worked I need to get sound and systems settings and my WiFi options and videos working on my laptop

Comment: I think I'm missing main alsa-base and unity a control a center andalsa-driver

Answer (score 0):

In 14.04 my sound doesn't work until I plug in headphones and pull it out again. Hopefully worth a try for you.